# Custom Devise/Warden strategy that requires intermediate step with user interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree, warden

I have a Spree application and I’m trying to implement a custom authentication strategy with Devise/Warden. The idea is that users are mapped to one or more companies. The first step in authenticating a user is to hit an external api endpoint that returns a list of associated companies. If no companies are returned, the user is invalid and I call fail!. However, if one or more companies are returned, my goal is to require the user to select an active company to use before they are authenticated and can continue to the site. Here is what I've got so far:

```
def valid?
  params[:email]
end

def authenticate!
  email = params[:email]
  companies = get_user_companies(email)

  if (companies.length > 0)
    user = User.find_by :email => email
    # have user select the active company here
    success!(user)
  else
    fail!("User has no companies")
  end
end

def get_user_companies(email)
  url = "http://localhost/user/#{email}/companies"
  JSON.parse(RestClient.get url, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
end
```

A user is not valid without a company, and the active company cannot be changed during a session. Is this possible? How would I go about implementing this? Would this step make more sense outside of an auth strategy? If so, where? Thanks!